Dynamically change min/max values of slider
In my application, I need to use a slider but I will not know what the bounds of the slider should be until after the user opens a file.
The documentation for slider doesn't list min and max properties as dynamic values. Is there a way to update the min/max values or are they fixed to whatever is defined when the object is created?

Does that language support anything like server side code that can generate the values for you to then feed into the front end to display them?  Such as , pre-render the results via the file, and then actually open it for them?  Or in other words can you make a variable on the front-end that you feed the numbers into those, and then display the varible in the spot where the static value would be ?

Oh nuts it appears programtic so you have to know the information before you run the program, what a paradox.

define min & max value as follows
zmin=0

zmax=100

vari=(zmin+zmax)/2 

So that slider hook is in the center, this is the default value of the slider
These can be changed as per requirement
slider is written as follows
<|{vari}|slider|min={zmin}|max={zmax}|> in markdown


min and max are dynamic values which means that they can be changed in run time.
If you open your file when the server is started, you can then:
from taipy import Gui 
import taipy.gui.builder as tgb


slider_value = 0

# don't use min and max as they are built-in Python functions.
min_slider = 0
max_slider = 100

def open_file(state):
    state.min_slider = get_min_from_your_file(...)
    state.max_slider = get_max_from_your_file(...)

# With Python API
with tgb.Page() as page:
    tgb.slider("{slider_value}", min="{min_slider}", max="{max_slider}")

# With Markdown
page = "<|{slider_value}|slider|min={min_slider}|max={max_slider}|>"


